# Wrong amplitude in the FFT for 10 seconds measured signal

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, spectrogram, stft, spectrum-estimation

I measured a signal with the Osziliscope that I generated with a signal generator. The signal is a pure sine wave with a frequency of 1 kHz and a peak amplitude of 2.5 V, I measured the signal for around 10 seconds. I did the FFT of this measured signal in Matlab, but the amplitude at 1 kHz was about 1.7 V and not 2.5 V as expected. Then I did a short Fourier transform of the signal (STFT), i.e. I divided it into segments (which overlapped) with the Blackman-Harris window and did a Fourier transform in each segment. Then I plotted the frequency-amplitude diagram and got the amplitude of the signal of about 2.5 V at 1kHz as expected. I then repeated the same thing with several signals (with a measurment time of 10 seconds) and always got the wrong amplitude in the FFT and the correct one in the STFT.

So my question is why the FFT does not show the expected amplitude of the my measrued signal at 1 kHz? Is it to do with the signal being non-stationary during the measurement? Or is the FFT not sufficient to determine the correct amplitude of each spectral component due to the long measurement time of 10 seconds? I really hope someone has an answer to this question, thank you in advance.

Comment: It'd help to attach the measurement (e.g. [ufile](https://ufile.io/), [drive](https://drive.google.com/), [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)).

Comment: If the peak amplitude is 2.5V, the FFT peaks should be ~1.25 V at -fc/2 and fc/2.